# Ubuntu 16.04 login screen is frozen after suspend

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, suspend, intel

I built my first Linux computer and installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. After installation, I performed a system update and installed the latest NVIDIA drivers for the GPU. Everything works fine while the computer is on; however, after the computer goes into the suspend state I cannot wake it. Pressing a key on the keyboard or clicking the mouse does nothing. If I press the power button, the computer will wake up but the screen remains black and the keyboard and mouse are not active. A list of my computer specs is provided below:

Motherboard = Gigabyte Z170N Gaming 5
CPU = Intel Core i7 6700 3.4GHz
Storage = Samsung 950 Pro, PCIe MVMe M.2, 256GB
RAM = G Skill Ripjaws V, DDR4 3200MHz, 32GB (2 x 16GB)
GPU = NVIDIA GTX 1060, 3GB
Monitor = Dell 4K, 27-inch screen, connected via DisplayPort cable
Power Supply = Corsair SF 600W
Linux kernel = 4.4.0-57-generic

I have the latest NVIDIA driver 375.26 installed for the GPU and selected the intel-microcode driver for the CPU.

[image: additional drivers]

Are there any suggestions on what I can do to make the suspend feature work properly? Is there a system log that I can view to see any errors that occur when waking from suspend?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid freezeing by unchecking "Allow Flipping" in Nvidia X server -> OpenGL.
But be prepared, that more issues [can occure.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570598/graphics-lags-after-suspend-ubuntu-16-04-nvidia-geforce-gtx-950m/42632208#42632208)

EDIT: With the newest system update and 381.09 from repository, the problem has not occured yet. No glitches and freezing so far after returning from suspend. I have 1060GTX.

Comment: I just wanted to sit and use my computer without these issues